# Is unit normal vector smooth

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a diffeomorphism f :$S_1 \rightarrow S2$ between two surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$.
If we define a map $_1 : _1 → R^3$ as follows:

if  ∈ $_1$, we put $ N_1(p) = \frac{a\times b}{\lvert a \times b\rvert}$
where ,  form a basis of $__1$.

I can prove that $N_1$ is both unitary and $\bot$ to $T_pS_1$ but I have trouble seeing why $N_1$ is smooth.

Comment: $a\times b$ is polynomial in the entries of $a$ and $b$. $|a\times b| = \sqrt{\langle a\times b, a\times b\rangle}$ which is smooth in the entries of $a$ and $b$. Then... (Note that this highly depends on the fact that $a$ and $b$ are smooth vector fields also)

Comment: How do I prove that a and b are smooth vector fields?

Comment: They are not if you don't require them to be. As it is, it seems you only have defined $a$ and $b$ at the point $p$, so $N_1$ is only defined at $p$, and there is no "smoothness" involved since $N_1$ is not a function

Comment: No it is for all p in S

Comment: Ok, but then you have to say something about $a$ and $b$.

Comment: In what sense? All I know is that they form the basis of $T_pS_1$ and therefore that they could be of the form $d_uf_p$ and $d_vf_p$ but not necessarily.

Comment: If you have no further assumption on $a$ and $b$ (like how they are built, how they are chosen despite spanning $T_pS$), then you *cannot* show anything.

Comment: This is what I am given. 
Let $ : _1 → _2$ be a local diffeomorphism between two surfaces $_1$ and $_2$ with $_2$ orientable. Let $_2$ be a unit normal field on $_2$. 
We define a map $_1 : _1 → R^3$ as follows:

if  ∈ $_1$, we put $ N_1(p) = \frac{a\times b}{\lvert a \times b\rvert}$
 where ,  form a basis of $__1$ satisfying $det\left((_)(), (_)(), _2(())\right) >0$

Show that $_1$ is a unit normal field on $_1$.